# Compromised phone

Tags: security

I have a stalker who has managed to intercept texts and maybe calls. I have changed phones, providers, and phone numbers and they always get in. I also believe my locations are being tracked. So my question...if I buy a 2nd phone with different phone number, leave the compromised phone at home and forward calls and texts to the new phone would my movements, calls and texts still be able to be intercepted. After all this harassment I would like to try something  else before I do a factory reset, since nothing else has worked...and law enforcement cant help...I've tried.

Comment: If "they always get in" you are making something wrong. Sell the old phone and get a new one. A skilled hacker can compromise a phone so that a factory reset does not delete everything. Make sure your Google account and the linked external email account (if the Google account is linked to one) have a secure password that is only used for this account (do not reuse passwords). I would recommend to change the Google account to 2-factor authentication and buy a FIDO hardware token like the one from [Google](https://cloud.google.com/titan-security-key?hl=en). Set a at least 6 digit PIN in Android.

Comment: I very changed phones, numbers and service providers, and change passwords frequently and use step authentication when available

Comment: May be the attacker is just good in social engineering. You can do a lot harm by just calling the service hotline and pretend to be someone else or send letters with forged signatures.

Comment: sounds like your stalker is working for NSA. police can't help, are you a criminal? Did you change provider, phone number and phone at same time? seriously someone must have physical access to your phone. or you are using the wrong apps (like whatsapp, instagram, etc)

Comment: The stalker is criminal..I dont know who the individual is but they are affiliated with one of the motorcycle groups that has a grudge with me...and no I am not a criminal....these groups are very good at harassment...and law enforcement doest have the knowledge nor equipment to track it down...pretty much told me unless I know specifically know who it is they cant help...yes changed them all at same time. Even used fact name and address on one. But I was hoping doing the call forward thing might give me a clue as to if it's someone who is close.

Comment: afaik traffic is encrypted, makes it very hard to attack nowadays (but not impossible) https://security.stackexchange.com/q/157970

Comment: tracking car is easy with magnetic gps tracker placed somewhere hidden. listen you one phone call is probably easier with some hidden microphone placed nearby, instead of attacking (unknown/randomly changed) phones itself

Comment: Well just to tell you the level of this...I did find a GPS tracker hidden in the engine compartment, attached to my battery...I am not positive the calls are being monitored...but texts for sure

Comment: I dont use WhatsApp,  I  use a app that blocks unknown numbers and texts.

Answer (score 1):

The degree to which you are being stalked is exceptional.  The attacker's apparent success in targeting you can only be possible because they are not dependent on the things you have changed.  They must have another angle you haven't discovered yet.  Perhaps someone with physical access to your phone/home, hidden cameras, etc.  Finding the GPS tracker indicates to me that this attacker is not fantasy, and means you must put a convincing end to this for your sanity.

You didn't mention changing your google account or how/if you restored data/apps from your old phone to the new one.  The latter being important if the attacker has ever had physical access to your phone.

Anyone accessing your google account would result in email notification messages that you would probably have noticed.  But if there was ever a malicious app installed it might have been auto-migrated to the new phone.

If you do get a second "secure" phone be sure to start a unique google account with it - and keep it disassociated with your old phone.

You must still find the security leak.  Start with locking down your home with video monitoring-using blink or equivalent.  Use a camera to monitor your home-safe-space for uninvited visitors when you are away.  Don't forget that the attacker may be someone you know and do not suspect.

Take the GPS tracker and put it somewhere where you can focus a camera on it.  Sooner or later your will try to retrieve it.

There will be a reason that motivates the attacker.  Only you may know what that might be, but use that as bait to predict their next move.

Comment: Too late on the tracker, I went to police and shortly after I found the tracker, but  unit was cut and wires connected  to battery we all that was left.. leaving compromised phone home while using another was my idea to see if I get any kind of response knowing me or the phone havnt moved. When I get contacted it always with a spoofed number, but I would still know if there is a reaction. No emails on the Google account  but when I've changed phones I've connected to existing  Google acct to retrieve contacts.